# Graph API: Same request with different album ID returns empty JSONObject?

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, access-token

I am using following code in my android app in a for loop of albumIDs to make requests for getting specific photo object information:

```
AsyncFacebookRunnerObj.request(currentAlbumID +"/photos?fields=id,name,source,created_time", new myRequestListner, refString);
```

I know the albumIDs of my friend's profile which I can see from my facebook profile. Though I can see all the albums I want to retrieve (they are public), but calls to this function still returns empty for some of albumIDs while for others it works perfectly fine.

When I access the albums using Graph API explorer i can retrieve all photos from all albums. Access_token in this case is different but I guess it is supposed to be different because in my case I am accessing it from app.

Please let me know what can be wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: I tried Graph API batch request from   (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6379092/android-facebook-graph-batch-api/6633724#6633724)instead of individual requests as mentioned above, still the result is same. I can't access photos in few albums but in others I can.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue with the FB JS SDK. Check that your json parser is parsing the album id as a string instead of a long/double (probably only a mixed-type language issue, but worth investigating).