# can we post on multiple user's Facebook wall at same time

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-social-plugins

Hi im developing an android app using facebook sdk in this app i want to post some message on multiple facebook friends wall at same time i mean user just select his facebook friends and enter message that he want to post and hit send button .is it possible to do?

Comment: You should not use feed stories as a communication channel between application users and their friends. That's why [Send](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/send/) and [Requests](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/) dialogs exists.

Comment: @JuicyScripter  thnx for reply yeah i try to use send dialog but its not working for me as it gives me  error error code:301

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is indeed possible.

In order to do that though you'll have to ask the user to grant your app the "[publish_stream](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/)" permission.
Once you have that you can post on his behalf.

To actually make the posts use the *request* method of the [Facebook object](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/androidsdk/request/) or [AsyncFacebookRunner object](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/androidsdk/ayncrequest/) (the later is preferable).

You can also use [Batch Requests](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/batch/) to make all the posts in one request, I've never tried it from android app, but since it's based on http request (like the entire api) it should be possible, you can for example check out this thread: [Android facebook graph batch api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6379092/android-facebook-graph-batch-api).

The only issue is that you'll need to create the UI for the friends selection yourself since there's no dialog in the sdk that handles this kind of functionality.

Comment: let me try this thnx for quick reply

Comment: do you have any idea about send dialog ??? as i try yo use batch request to post but no luck :( and have some doubts while using AsyncFacebookRunner can you help me out with this

Comment: The send dialog from my experience doesn't work on android sdk, and based on the javascript version (and the documentation) it won't help you anyhow since when opening it up you can specify only one user (and then the user can add more). What do you mean by "no luck" and why do you have some "doubts"?