# Posting on multiple friend's wall using Facebook 3.0 after the Feb 6th change

Tags: android, facebook-batch-request

I have found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10222668/1767260) that we can use Batch rqeuest to post on multiple friend's wall and I have tried to do so using graph API.But I got the following error.But I can post with feed dialog to single user.As of Feb 6th Facebook no longer allows us to post to someone's wall using the graph API.Then How can I user Batch request to post on friend's wall.

> {Response:  responseCode: 200, graphObject: null, error: {HttpStatus:
>   403, errorCode: 200, errorType: OAuthException, errorMessage: (#200)
>   Feed story publishing to other users is disabled for this
>   application}, isFromCache:false}

The code used is

```
RequestBatch requestBatch = new RequestBatch();
            for (final String requestId : requestIds) {
                requestBatch.add(new Request(Session.getActiveSession(), 
                        requestId+ "/feed", postParams, HttpMethod.POST, new Request.Callback() {
                    public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                        Log.e("Response", ""+response.toString());
                    }
                }));
            }
```

where requestIds is array of ids.   Please help me.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> As of Feb 6th Facebook no longer allows us to post to someone's wall using the graph API.Then How can I user Batch request to post on friend's wall.

Not at all, of course.

> OAuthException, errorMessage: (#200) Feed story publishing to other users is disabled for this application

What is possibly unclear about that?

Comment: Then How can I use Batch request to post that is my question

Comment: You __can not__, because posting to other user's walls via API is not possible any more. What about this don't you understand?

Comment: Ok. Is there any other way to post on multiple friend's wall?

Comment: No, there is not. All you can do is call the Feed dialog multiple times, to have the user post a message to one friend at a time.

Comment: Thank you for your response and time.